# Как перевести двоичную систему в десятичную систему счисления без базовых функции?

Tags: php

Привет Всем! Вот такая у меня задача перевести с двоичной СЧ в десятичную. К примеру 1001 = 9 в десятичной. Вот нашёл функцию стандартную convert_basic(), но к сожалению стандартную функцию в задаче использовать нельзя. Кто поможет, буду очень признательный.

Comment: > Blockquote К примеру 1001 = 1 в десятичной

Бред полный 1001 в десятичной системе будет 9 но никак не 1

Comment: Отпечатка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function mybindec($bin) {
  $n = 1;
  $dec = 0;
  $bin = (string)$bin;
  for ($i = strlen($bin)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($bin{$i}=="1") $dec = $dec + $n;
    $n = $n * 2;
    }
  return $dec;
  }
```

Надеюсь, INT устроит? т.е. целые числа. с FLOAT чуть сложнее.

Comment: Теперь нет) Надо было строку на вход слать, добавил принудительный перевод.

Comment: А Вам не сложно было обьяснить знаки
*=
+=
и почему i в {$i}

Comment: Для строки, уже не помню почему, обращение `$str[$i]` - некошерно. То ли deprecated, то ли просто некошерно)) **`$a *= $b`** эквивалентно **`$a = $a * $b`**, "+=" по аналогии.

Comment: А можно ли как-то это переписать? Так как Ваши объяснения не для моего уровня.

Comment: Кроме строки, обращение как к массиву может ворнинги выдавать. Операторы исправил.

Comment: А теперь понял =)), спасибо. А еще можете обьяснить более руким зыком что {} - делают? Я так понимаю программа по одному символу берет и один символ содержится в $i?

Comment: `$bin` - строка. `$bin[$i]` или `$bin{$i}` - $i-й символ строки, начиная с нулевого. Например

    $str = 'abc';
    echo $str{0}; // a
    echo $str{1}; // b
    echo $str{2}; // c

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
function mybindec($bin) {
  $n   = 0;
  $dec = 0;
  $bin = (string)$bin;
  $len = strlen($bin);
   while($len>=$n){
     if(intval(substr($bin,$n,1))) $dec += pow(2,$len-$n-1); 
     $n++;
   }
  return $dec;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Внесу свою лепту.

```
function bin2dec($bin) {
    $index = strlen($bin) - 1;
    $result = 0;
    $mult = 1;
    while ($index >= 0) {
            $result += ($bin[$index--] == '1' ? $mult : 0);
            $mult <<= 1;
    }
    return $result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, автору требовался примерно такой ответ:

```
function bin2oct($s_bin){
    $digit = array("000"=>"0", "001"=>"1", "010"=>"2", "011"=>"3", "100"=>"4", "101"=>"5", "110"=>"6", "111"=>"7");

    if($i=strlen($s_bin)%3) $s_binary = str_repeat("0", 3-$i) . $s_bin;
    $s_octal = "";
    for ($i=strlen($s_binary); $i>0; $i-=3) $s_octal = $digit[substr($s_binary,$i-3,3)] . $s_octal;

    return "0".$s_octal;
}

$s_bin = "1001";
sscanf(bin2oct($s_bin), "%o", $num);
$string_dec = sprintf("%d", $num);

printf("binary=%s decimal=%s", $s_bin, $string_dec);
```