# Как перевести двоичную систему в восьмеричную систему счисления без базовых функции?

Tags: алгоритм, php, системы-счисления

Привет всем! Вот такая у меня задача перевести с двоичной СЧ в восмеричную. К примеру, 1001 = 11 в десятичной. Вот нашёл стандартную функцию `convert_basic()`, но, к сожалению, стандартную функцию в задаче использовать нельзя. Кто поможет, буду очень признательный. Сам процесс умеею делать на листочке, но как захватить 3 символа - не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37683/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) не будем считать повтором. 1001(8) - это 513(10).

```
function myoctdec($oct) {
  $n = 1;
  $dec = 0;
  $oct = (string)$oct;
  for ($i = strlen($oct)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $dec = $dec + ( (int)$oct{$i} * $n );
    $n = $n * 8;
    }
  return $dec;
  }
```

Переделал свой ответ оттуда. *Могли бы и сами, к слову.*

А я сюда добавлю. Корректно работает с системами 2-10, но, возможно, не лучшее в плане производительности решение. **UPD после скайпа, + поддержка до основы 32**

```
function myconvert($num, $from = 10, $to = 10) {
  $sym = array( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V' );
  $val = array_flip($sym);
  $n = 1;
  $result = '';
  $f = strtoupper((string)$num);
  for ($i = strlen($f)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $result = $result + ( $val[$f{$i}] * $n );
    $n = $n * $from;
    }
  if ($to == 10) return $result;
  $result2 = '';
  while ($result > 0) {
    $result2 = $sym[($result % $to)].$result2;
    $result = floor($result / $to);
    }
  return $result2;
  }
echo myconvert(1001, 2, 8); // 11
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое человеческое! А насчет переделки пытался только намудрил много лишнего

Comment: Не за что) А галку?)

Comment: А у Вас skype есть, можно я буду у Вас спрашивать вопросы, чтобы не флудить тут

Comment: Вопрос свой перечитайте) причем тут 

> восьмеричную СЧ в десятичную

и (2)->(8)?) Скайп m4d_5h4d0w, но я не каждый день в нем.

Comment: Извините меня, отпечатался, зайдите пожалуйста в скайп

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос в заглавии:

```
printf("binary=%b octal=%o", $n=0b1001, $n);
```

Результат:

```
binary=1001 octal=11
```

Если, конечно, исходное число - не строка.